# mounted in Vue doesn't want to give a $route.name

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I don't know I'm about quite Vue, spent a day learning all hooks routes, tried throug regular hooks `created`, `mounted` and it still gives me `null`. Here is my component App where all other components are plugged in. I'm calling here `mounted` hook, so 
basically it totally rendered this component, and we have a path + I wrapped evrythin in `$nextTick` just to be sure and it still returns me `null` name of a current router if I come to the website not from main url, but from children as for instance url/boys. I gave up long time ago getting this name of a router in children component where I need it, thought alright I'll just path it to children `<the-nav/>` that's where I need it. But it doesnt work event in parent and I need only name of a current router when I enter the website. That's it, sounds easy but went throught hell.

```
<template>
      <div id="app">
        <the-header/>
        <the-nav/>
        <div id="app__inner">
          <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
            <router-view />
          </transition>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      import TheHeader from "@/components/TheHeader.vue";
      import TheNav from "@/components/TheNav.vue"

      export default {
        components : {
          TheHeader,
          TheNav
        },
        mounted()
        {
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            console.log(this.$router.currentRoute.name);
          })
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: have you tried using this.$route instead of this.$router ?

Comment: `this.$router.currentRoute.name` is the same as `this.$route.name` There is no need for `$nextTick` - if you are already inside this hook then the route has already been changed.

Comment: Can you try `console.log(this.$router.currentRoute);`?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the exposed router functions inside this befoureRouteEnter function, used like so:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    console.log(to.name);
    next();
  },
```

Please read some documentation on router Navigation guards:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `name` set on the router, otherwise `name` will be `undefined`. For example...

```js
const routes = [
  { 
    path: "/", 
    component: Home, 
    name: "Home"  // Make sure route is named
  },
];
```

Then in component you should be able to access the name in mounted hook, without `nextTick` (like mentioned in comment):

```js
mounted() {
  alert(`Route name is: ${this.$route.name}`);
}
```

**[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-routing-example-xty9j)**